# Extending/changing the parameter type of an interface in an external (npm) modules

Tags: typescript

I have a project in where I use an external library. The library provides an interface (along with other typings) for all of its structure.

In one particular case I want to pass a `string[]` to an interface parameter typed to be a `string`. This gives an error.

```
import {ExampleInterface} from 'example';

declare module 'example' {
  export interface ExampleInterface {  // TS2428: All declarations of 'ExampleInterface' must have identical type parameters.
    exampleParameter: string[];
  }
}
```

Is it possible to work around this?